# Syncronizing 2 databases using hibernate - use save(), update() or saveOrUpdate()?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, session

I am trying to sync multiple databases whose items have GUID for IDs, meaning that one item has the same ID on all databases.

My question is:
If i modify or create on item on 1 database, and want to synchronize this change to the other database should i:

1.) Check if the item is new or just modified, if its new then use the save() function, if its modified then use the update() function

or

2.)Do not check if its new or modified and just use the saveOrUpdate() function?

Comment: Might I ask...why? If you want the databases to be the same, use master-slave replication. If you only want this particular data to be shared across databases, perhaps you should re-think your application design such that this data only comes from one database? I will promise you this: whenever you store the same data in two places, it **WILL** get out of sync.

Comment: i have 1 central database on a server, ond local databases on tablet which dont allways have internet connection, so if 1 local database adds or updates an item, then its transfered to the central one, which transfers it to all others

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes more sense. I would just track a "last updated" and "last synced" time on the client. Whenever you establish an internet connection, pull all objects where the last updated > last synced, and push them up to the server. (Or, for the server down to the client - same thing)

Comment: oh, all of that is in place, i just dont kkow which is the correct function to use, save(), update(), saveOrUpdate(), i mean when saving an item into the other database using hibernate sessions

Comment: Resiliency sounds more important than performance to you. If the last sync date is before the last updated date (or if it's null), then you know SOMETHING has changed. I'd just use `saveOrUpdate` at that point.

Comment: so the function saveOrUpdate() will recognize if in the db is no item with the id from the other databas(new Item) or if there is one and needs to only be update (updated item)? thats really important for me

Comment: Right. Really, I would just call it `sync`. It's then the job of the recipient to determine if it has that object or not. If it does, it should perform an update. If it doesn't, it should perform an insert. The client shouldn't be responsible for knowing the state of the server

Comment: ok, great, 1 other thing, u mentioned performance before, it actually is pretty important, every table has a dateCreated and dateModified with which a can figure out if an item is new or updated, but its ofc more complicated than using saveOrUpdate(), i mean, there will be alot more code to write, so is there a great diference between using saveOrUpdate() instead of save() and update() ?

Comment: Performance should always be important. But the general rule of thumb in technology is that guaranteed resiliency takes time. This is a case in which you should take a marginal performance hit (again, fairly marginal) over risking poor data. Knowing ahead of time if you need to insert or update will be yield better performance, but it will also lead to poor results. Your `saveOrUpdate` method could very easily determine if it needs to insert or update by a quick primary key select (on the ID). That should be a minimal hit.

Comment: ok, if its just a minimal hit, then i will use saveOrUpdate(), can you please compile all of this stuff into an answer so that i can accept it, you really helped me out here, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your use case in the comments, I think the best approach is to track (on both the client and server) when the last updated/last synced time was. In the event that the last sync time is null, or comes before the last updated time, you know that the data needs to be synced.

Now, on to the heart of your question: how to sync it. The client need not know the state of a server when it sends an object to you. In fact, it shouldn't. Consider the case where the client posts an object, your server receives it and process it, but the connection dies before your client receives the response. This is a very valid scenario and will result in a mis-match of data. As a result, any way that you try to determine whether or not the server has received an object (from the client) is likely to end up in a bad state.

The best solution is really to create an idempotent endpoint on the server (an upsert method, or `saveOrUpdate` as you referred to it in your question) which is able to determine what to do with the object. The server can query it's database by primary key to determine if it has the object or not. If it does, it can update, if not, it can insert.

Understandably, performance is important as well as the data. But, stick with primary keys in the database and that one additional select query you add should be extremely minimal (sub-10ms). If you really want to squeeze some more performance out, you could always use memcache or redis as a caching layer to determine if you have a certain GUID in your database. This way, you only have to hit memory (not your database) to determine if an object exists or not. The overhead of that would be measured only in the latency between your web server and cache server (since a memory read is incredibly cheap).

**tl;dr**

Upsert (or `saveOrUpdate`) is the way to go. Try not to track the state of one machine on another.

Comment: Just for clarification, with saveOrUpdate() i mean: `Session session = createSessionMethod(); session.saveOrUpdate(item);` I think you missunderstood me

Comment: @M364M4Ncro Indeed that does change things, I had assumed you had your own method doing this. Hibernate will actually incorrectly try to update in this case. You're going to push up an object that *does* have an ID (a GUID generated by your client). In this case, Hibernate will perform an update, even though the object may not exist in the server yet. The solution is simple. Rather than calling saveOrUpdate, you should, on your own, try to fetch the object from the database. If you get a result, you can perform `saveOrUpdate` (or, just `update` - doesn't matter). If not, then `persist`

Comment: ok, thx, man, this saving stuff in hibernate is really complicated

Comment: could i use session.save(item) if the item is not already in the database?

Comment: OK, thx for explaining this to me, this whole thing really got me confused, and it will probably confuse other ppl aswell, so could you update your answer so everyone can see this